# ASP.NET MVC5 - RenderPartial() doesn't executed after returning Partial View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

I have the following code:

**View**:

```
@model IEnumerable<FormBuilder.Model.Formular>

<div id="divAktiveFormulare">
   @{ Html.RenderPartial("Formular/TableAllFormulare", Model.Where(model => model.Status == FormularStatus.Aktiv).ToList()); }
</div>

<div id="divArchivierteFormulare">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("Formular/TableAllFormulare", Model.Where(model => model.Status == FormularStatus.Archiviert).ToList()); }
</div>

function btnArchivieren(e) {
   $.ajax({
       url: 'Url.Action("Archive", "Formular")',
       data: { id: e.target.name },
       success: function (data) {
          $('#divArchivierteFormulare').html(data);
       }
   });         
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     List<Formular> aktiveformulare = _formularManager.GetAllFormulare();
     return View(aktiveformulare);
}  

public ActionResult Archive(int id)
{
      Formular formular = _formularManager.GetFormularByID(id);

      if (formular != null)
      {
           formular.Status = FormularStatus.Archiviert;
           _formularManager.UpdateFormular(formular);
      }

      return PartialView("Formular/TableAllFormulare", _formularManager.GetAllFormulare());
 }
```

I have two divs (`divAktiveFormulare` and `divArchivierteFormulare`). In each of them a partial view is rendered. The partial views show a table of the model-items (model is an `IEnumerable`), and each has a filtered model after an enumaration (f.e. `Html.RenderPartial("Formular/TableAllFormulare", model => model.Status == FormularStatus.Archiviert`).

While loading the index-page for the first time, everything works perfectly. I can set a breakpoint at the `RenderPartial()`-lines and it will stop there. Both partial views show its tables correctly after the filtered model.

On my page I have a button and by pressing it it will start the Javascript `btnArchivieren`, which send an ajax to the controller. The action will return a `Partial View()` with the updated model.

But now my brakepoint at `RenderPartial()` will not be fired again. Well, the div is updated yeah, but without filtering the model for the partial views (`Model.Where(model => model.Status == FormularStatus.Archiviert`). Both partial views are showing the table without filtering by enumaration. Like like i said, my brakepoint wasn't even fired.

What am I doing wrong? 
Why aren't the `RenderPartial()`-lines executed after returning the partial view from the controller with an updated model?

Answer (score 0):

When you use :

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Formular/TableAllFormulare", Model.Where(model => model.Status == FormularStatus.Aktiv).ToList()); }
```

You are telling your application that it has to call your partial view "Formular/TableAllFormulare" with the data you provided.

It's done only while rendering all the page, not by calling it in ajax.

It's the code inside that partial view that will be executed by the ajax call.

Anyway, I would suggest to place your breakpoint in your controller at this line :

```
Formular formular = _formularManager.GetFormularByID(id);
```

For it's that line that will be exectued, and probably where the error is hiding.

---

EDIT :

You'll just have to do that :

```
return PartialView("Formular/TableAllFormulare", _formularManager.GetAllFormulare().Where(model => model.Status == FormularStatus.Archiviert).ToList());
```

I hope you understand why it won't work as you expected it at first, so tell me if you don't. I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: With `$('#divArchivierteFormulare').html(data);}` in the ajax i actually call also the `Html.RenderPartial` line. I've already implemented a couple of partial views with exactely this behavior, therefore I'm confused for what reason my pv isn't loaded.

Comment: Oh, I see.

There is no "error" in your code, you are just expecting the "Where" in your "div" to work while doing your ajax.

This does not work like that. As I was trying to explain you, when you do that :

`$('#divArchivierteFormulare').html(data);`

You replace the DOM content in your rendered page by the "data" object, which is the content of your "Formular/TableAllFormulare" partial.